# Limit displayed characters in cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

Is there a way to make Excel only display the first x characters and replace the rest with '...' ?

Example:
My cell contains `This is a long text a really really loooong text it goes on and on and on`.
I want Excel to display it as `This is a long text ...`

I want to do it without having to modify the actual content (i.e. if I copy that cell and paste it somewhere else, I want to still get the complete long text), or making a truncated copy of that column and then hiding the original.

Comment: no, I don't think there would be a way to do what you need. You can use some workaround you've already described not wishing to do.

Comment: aw ... that's too bad ....

Answer (score 1):

yes, this is easy.

in column A, insert your text

in column B, type ...

set the column A text width to the desired # of characters.
set text wrapping to off.

this will display "this is a long text ..." from "this is a long text that goes on and on and on and on."

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this I can think of, and not one I'd *ever* recommend, is some combination of a VBA function and the `Worksheet.SelectionChange` event to trap the original text, squirrel it away somewhere and replace it with the truncated version. If the cell is then selected in the future then the original text is replaced so it can be copied etc.

This would be extremely messy, slow and might not even work satisfactorily. If you have a really pressing need and the range of cells this would be carried out on is limited then it may be worth pursuing, but on a whole worksheet/workbook basis, forget it.